# Adding Components To JScrollPane Panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am really having a problem to make my panel scrollable. First, I am not fun of using Layout Managers in Java. I find it easier to just layout my panel manually. Anyway, I have a panel and I want to be Scrollable thus I used JScrollPane with the panel as its parameter. However, whenever I add components to my panel, the scrollpane doesn't work and I have no idea why. Please help with my project. Here is the code:

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setBounds(5,50,510,540);
    mainPanel.setLayout(null);
    mainPanel.setOpaque(false);
    displayPanel.add(mainPanel);

    JPanel childPanel = new JPanel();
    childPanel.setLayout(null);
    childPanel.setSize(510,540);
    childPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (childPanel)
    scroll.setSize(510,540);
    childPanel.setAutoscrolls(true);
    int y = 20, height = 100 ;

    for(int i=0 ; i<10; i++){
        JButton panel = new JButton();
        panel.setBounds(5,y,100,height);
        y = y + height;
        childPanel.add(panel);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    }

    mainPanel.add(scroll);
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: `I am really having a problem to make my panel scrollable` - don't use a null layout!!! `I am not fun of using Layout Managers in Java.` - yes, well a JScrollPane is designed to work with a panel that uses layout managers. If you want scrolling use a layout manager. `the scrollpane doesn't work and I have no idea why.` - because you are using a null layout.

Comment: I see. I think I really have to read about Layout Mangers. Thanks by the way.

Comment: And I gave you a link to the Swing tutorial in your last answer for a reason. It teaches you Swing basics. There is a section on layout managers.

Comment: Okay. I am actually reading it right now. Thanks a lot sir.